# My 2015 x trail was damaged so replaced ECU (used) and car did take self but still wasn't starting, now car not recognising the key?

Tags: nissan, electronic-control-module, key, x-trail

Nissan X Trail not recognising the key.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I see you have an issue, what exactly is your question?

Comment: In most modern vehicles the key is coded to the immobiliser, which may well be located in the ECU.